# Replacing save button with submit for approval in the edit page

Tags: apex, page-layout, approval-process, visualforce

I want to replace the save button with submit for approval in an edit page of record. So that every time a user tries to edit the record then it won't be saved right away rather it will be submitted for approval. Btw i am using standard salesforce page.

Comment: If you want to *save* their edits in a deferred way, and only *commit* them to the record once they are approved, then this is actually a fairly complicated request. I think you would need a separate approval object and a trigger. Perhaps someone will have a simpler recommendation, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace the "Save" button like that. If you absolutely need something that automatically sends a record for approval, I recommend you write a trigger that manually does that on any save.

If you follow the sample in [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm) you will be able to see how it's done.

This snippet will prove particularly useful

```
    // Create an approval request for the object
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
    req1.setObjectId(*<Object ID>*);

    // Submit on behalf of a specific submitter
    req1.setSubmitterId(*<User Id>*);

    // Submit the record to specific process and skip the criteria evaluation
    req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('*<ProcessName>*');
    req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);

    // Submit the approval request for the object
    Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
```

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I know you know better than to post a Link Only Answer. :) Can you include some content?

Comment: It's pure code.... didn't think it was completely relevant.... but I can eat my own dog poo and do that. :D

Comment: Yeah, the point is just that links can break, so that content could be lost entirely. Especially with SF documentation it seems.

Comment: I know, I know... I should've known better and got lazy. :)